# Как в MySql осуществить обход древа

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется вот такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_product1` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_image` text NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

А это таблица назначения

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_product11` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_price` double NOT NULL,
  `product_status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `product_image` text NOT NULL,
  `product_description` text NOT NULL,
  `product_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Как вывести данные из таблицы `tbl_product11` где `category_id tbl_product11` =  `product_id tbl_product1`.

Помогите с решением , я уже многое перепробовал, не могу вывести товар относящийся к под категории.

Вот пример что я хочу получить

```
if (isset($_GET['category1_id'])) {
  $query = "SELECT v.product_id, v.product_name, v.category_id, b.product_id , v.product_image FROM tbl_product1 v, tbl_product11 b WHERE v.category_id = b.product_id AND b.product_id ='" .
    $_GET['category1_id'] .
    "' ORDER BY v.product_id DESC";
```

в этом выводе я не уверен, просто в виде примера привёл

Comment: Можете привести пример выборки, что хочется получить?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov - Вот пример что я хочу получить  `else if (isset($_GET['category1_id'])) {
   $query = 
   
  "SELECT v.product_id, v.product_name, v.category_id, b.product_id , v.product_image
  
  FROM tbl_product1 v, tbl_product11 b 
  
  WHERE v.category_id = b.product_id AND b.product_id ='".$_GET['category1_id']."' 
  
  ORDER BY v.product_id DESC";` в этом выводе я не уверен, просто в виде примера привёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используй JOIN

```
select p11.product_name from tbl_product1 as p1
LEFT JOIN tbl_product11 as p11
ON p1.product_id = p11.category_id
WHERE p1.product_id = $_GET['category1_id']
```

Comment: Я проверил ваш ответ , не сработало.

Comment: я немного поспешил - исправил под вас

Comment: Спасибо вам, ваш код работает ) ! Я покопался у себя в приложении где получаю данные с базы и также у себя нашёл ошибку , `JsonArrayRequest(GET_CATEGORY_DETAIL2 + product_id `  product_id я передавал не как String а как Long. Спасибо большое за помощь.